# How to get data connected by ForeignKey?

Tags: django, listview, django-queryset

I'm new in Django. I'm trying to retrieve all the Tags associated with a Question.

I have two classes on `models.py`.

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tag_on = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My `views.py`.

```
class QuestionListView(ListView):
    model = Questions #assign model to display
    template_name = 'index.html'

class TagListView(ListView):
    model = Tag
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'tag_list'
    queryset = ?
```

I have added this to  my `index.html`.

```
{% for val in object_list %}
  {{ val.id }} <br>
  {{ val.title }} <br>
{% endfor %}

{% for tag in tag_list %}
  {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried few `queryset` like this but none of them worked.

```
queryset = Tag.objects.all().get(Tag.id=Questions.id)
queryset = Tag.objects.select_related('tag_on__id').get()
```

How do I define queryset properly to address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try doing this.

```
queryset=Tag.objects.filter(tag_on__id=<your_id>)
```

As far as how to render it in the template.

You can do something like this.

```
def view(request):
  return render(request,'index.html',context={queryset:Tag.objects.filter(tag_on__id=<your_id>)})
```

and in your index.html

```
{% for i in queryset %}
  {{i.name}} // or any fields that you want
{% endfor %}
```

For class based approach:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class yourview(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, kwargs):
      context = super(yourview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['queryset'] = Tag.objects.filter(tag_on__id=<your_id>)
      return context
```

Comment: It generates following error:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'questions' into field. Choices are: id, name, tag_on, tag_on_id`

Comment: did you use two underscores(__) after questions?

Comment: The name of the model field is tag_on not questions.

Comment: Sure. This works. But I can't figure out what is actually happening in `(tag_on__id=<id>)`. Can you explain this?

Comment: And how do I render this through template?

Comment: Actually, it has to be `tag_on__id` in order to work since the field name is `tag_on`.
So, `questions__id` didn't work but `tag_on__id` did.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry. So, the tag_on__id refers to the foreign key reference to the questions table. id refers to the questions table and double underscore tells that it is a relation. Eventhough you do not create a column called id in the questions table, django creates one for you as a primary key which you can see in the postgresql(or others) database using pgadmin or console. You can read more about it in the link above.

Comment: That method of rendering is for function based views but I'm using class-based views. Can you help me do this using class-based view approach?

Comment: What is the variable that is to be rendered in template?

Comment: It's `queryset` as you can see in `context["queryset"]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your efforts. As I've two classes in my views, how do I map both of them in the `urls`?

Comment: I am not sure why you want two separate views for the exact same function. You can do something like `url(r'^$', Firstview.as_view())` and for the second view, you have to add something else to the url other than leaving them empty as the empty one is already been used by the Firstview. Something like `url(r'^/second$',SecondView.as_view())`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to  retrieve all the Tags associated with a particular Question:

```
question = Questions.objects.get(<some_condition>)
queryset = Tag.objects.filter(tag_on=question)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. 
How do I render it through template? The way I did didn't work.